# Boundary of simplex,homotopy theory

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplex

In Homotopy Ttheory,
the simplicial set ∂Δn is the subobject of hom(-,n)=Δn which is generated by
the (n − 1)-simplices $d^i, 0 ≤ i ≤ n$,however I do not understand here what are the morphisms in Δn$_k$=hom(k,n) for k other than $n-1$.I.e. what more precisely means "generated" here.

Comment: Any subset of simplicies of a simplicial set generates a simplicial set that you can think about externally: the intersection of all sub simplicial sets containing the simplicies, or internally: the set of all simplicies given by compositions of face and degeneracy maps applied to the generating set of simplicies.

Comment: The morphisms $k\to n$ are the (nonstrict) order preserving maps $\{0,1,\ldots, k\} \to \{0,1,\ldots, n\}$.